# Neo4J Multi Tenancy and Role Based Access to Nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to define a user management and permissions model for Neo4j. I have a web application (Angular 2) that connects to Neo4j via an API (KOANEO4J). Neo4j is the only database or persistent storage that the application uses. Through the application a user can add/edit/delete content which uses the API to carry out these instructions in Neo4j by running Cypher Statements. Up to now I have not worried about supporting multiple users but as a next step I am starting to think about this.

The product will be used by multiple different companies and each company will have multiple users so I need some way to support this. The model I am considering in Neo4J is as follows:

An "Orgaization" is represented by a node and it can have 1 or more "Organization Catalogs". All of the nodes belonging to that catalog will be children of one of the "Organization Catalogs".

[image]

Each user will also be represented by a node in the database. They will belong to an Organisation. They will have certain access permissions on an Organization Catalog identified by a an edge.

[image]

1. I am looking for some advice on whether or not this is an appropriate model to follow or if there are any examples or documents that describe how to achieve this in Neo4j.
2. If I do implement this model then would it be better to model the permissions as seperate nodes so a user is connected to a permission  node (e.g. Read Only Access) that is then connected to the Organization Catalog.
3. Any suggestions on how I would actually get the API to work with this type of model. I'm sure I can pass the User Id to Neo4j as part of each query and then filter the results to show only nodes the user has access to but this doesn't seem like a very elegant solution - it also means that all of the security would be dependant on carefully written Cypher queries that don't leak data that a user isnt supposed to access.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for some advice on whether or not this is an appropriate
>   model to follow or if there are any examples or documents that
>   describe how to achieve this in Neo4j.

The answer for this question is: it depends. Remember that when modelling a graph database you should consider the queries that are asked to the database. If this model fits the queries that you are asking to the database then this model is appropriated, otherwise, not. Take a look in the Chapter 5 (Graphs in the Real World) of the book Graph Databases (by Ian Robison, Jim Webber and Emil Eifrem. Available for download [here](https://neo4j.com/graph-databases-book/)). This chapter shows the modelling process of an Authorization and Access Control system in Neo4j. Can be enlightening and helpful to you.

> If I do implement this model then would it be better to model the
>   permissions as seperate nodes so a user is connected to a permission
>   node (e.g. Read Only Access) that is then connected to the
>   Organization Catalog.

Again, it depends. Do it if the Permission entity has connection to others entities of your application besides an User and an Organization Catalog. Otherwise I believe that your permission can be modeled as a relationship between an user and an organization catalog.

> Any suggestions on how I would actually get the API to work with this
>   type of model. I'm sure I can pass the User Id to Neo4j as part of
>   each query and then filter the results to show only nodes the user has
>   access to but this doesn't seem like a very elegant solution - it also
>   means that all of the security would be dependant on carefully written
>   Cypher queries that don't leak data that a user isnt supposed to
>   access.

Maybe is a good idea add another layer of software between your AngularJS client app and the Neo4j database. This way in this new layer of software (a Node.js application, for example) you can implement a access control system, then verifiy if the authenticated user can access the resource that is being requested.